# Check if class property has been set

Tags: c#, equality, setter, getter

Lets assume I have a User class

```
public Class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Level {get;set;}
}


User user1 = new User();
user1.Name = "name";
user1.Surname = "Surname";
user1.Level = 0;

User user2 = new User();
user2.Name = "name";
user2.Surname = "Surname";
```

When I check `user1.Level == user2.Level` it returns `true` since default `int` value is `0`.

So is there any way to do that I can understand that Level property of `user2` is not set so that I can say these two are not identical?

Comment: You could use `int?`, but then you would probably better setting level 1 as the default entry level. Your question is a bit of an XY problem.. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You could set the default to (for example) -1 in the constructor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. If you use `int?` as type for `Level`, it will be NULL when not setted.

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int? Level { get; set; }
}
```

2. You can use the setter of the `Level` attribute and set a boolean when you set a new value, if the other proposed solution is not good for you. Example:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    private int _Level;
    private bool _hasLevel;
    public int Level
    { 
        get { return _Level; } 
        set { _Level= value; _hasLevel = true; } 
    }

    public bool HasLevel { get { return _hasLevel; } }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option (in addition to the others suggested) is to set the value to something other than `0` in the class constructor. It's common to use `-1`.

```
public Class User
{
    public User() 
    {
        Level = -1;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Level {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Nullable`

```
public Class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int? Level {get;set;}
}
```

It will have by default value null instead of value 0.

for more about `Nullable` look at [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can change your class to make Level nullable.

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int? Level {get;set;}
}
```