# Check if an int property has value assigned to it coming from an HTTP request

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

Good day fellow programmers,

I have a simple domain expressed as follows:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Quote> Quotes { get; set; } = new List<Quote>();
}
```

and

```
public class Quote
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }  // Just a navigation property.
    public int PersonId { get; set; }   // The foreign key for Person.
}
```

I'm working on a PUT endpoint in ASP.NET Core that takes a Quote object from the body of the HTTP request in order to update the quote text. However, I want to make sure that the person who said the quote is not being changed along with the text.

When passed as a JSON, the object looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 69,
    "text": "nice quote"
}
```

Since the `PersonId` does not necessarily have to be included, it's sent back as `null` and therefore I must ignore it when comparing to the current value to see if it's different, but the C# compiler won't let me do that because integers are non-nullable value types, making `PersonId == null` a meaningless statement.

So my question is: is there a way to check for the "valueless" of an integer without using `int?` in the POCO class?

Let me know if any further information is needed. Thank you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495699/check-if-class-property-has-been-set

Comment: If you don't want to send PersonId back - don't do it. Create another type to represent returned Quote without PersonId property.

Comment: I tried the approach in the linked post and although it worked, now I have that boolean field being sent in the response along with the relevant fields LOL which is a bit awkward. Thanks for the insight anyway. Haven't tried @Fabio 's solution yet though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for the default value of `int`, which is 0. I'm assuming in some sort of data store, you will never have a person ID equal to 0 (or even less than 0).

```cs
public void Put(Quote quote) 
{
   if (quote.PersonId == default) 
   {
      // person id is the default value of int (0)
   }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the most simple possible way in my case, but I have worked in a place where they had a few clients with negative IDs in their ERP database xD