# Is there a way to know if object property value is already set or is it default?

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for a way to find out if object property value is already set or if it's still default.
My class:

```
class TestModel
{
    public string TestStringProperty { get; set; }
    public int TestIntProperty { get; set; }
    public bool TestBoolProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and I initialize it:

```
TestModel model = new()
{
    TestBoolProperty = false,
    TestStringProperty = "testValue",
    TestIntProperty = 1,
};
```

Later I run this code, to get current and default values for those properties:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in model.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    object? currentValue = model.GetType()?.GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name)?.GetValue(model, null);
    object? defaultValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(Activator.CreateInstance(dummyModel.GetType()), null);
    Trace.WriteLine($"Current value for property {propertyInfo.Name} is: {currentValue?.ToString()}");
    Trace.WriteLine($"Default value for property {propertyInfo.Name} is: {defaultValue?.ToString()}");
}
```

and the output is:

```
Current value for property TestStringProperty is: testValue
Default value for property TestStringProperty is: 
Current value for property TestIntProperty is: 1
Default value for property TestIntProperty is: 0
Current value for property TestBoolProperty is: False
Default value for property TestBoolProperty is: False
```

However, TestBoolProperty (bool) value is the same as default value (false). If I hadn't initialized it, it would still be default.

**My question:**
Is there a way to find out if this property is set, even if its value the same as default?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if class property has been set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495699/check-if-class-property-has-been-set)

Answer (score 1):

Use backing fields and a boolean value:

```cs
class TestModel
{
    private string _testStringProperty;
    private bool _testStringPropertySet;

    public string TestStringProperty
    {
        get { return _testStringProperty; }
        set { _testStringProperty = value; _testStringPropertySet = true; }
    }
```

Then you can check the boolean field in addition to the property value.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's no way to tell the difference between a default value and an assigned value if that value is the same as the default. @DiplomacyNotWar  provided a way around that. Another option is to use `Nullable` and check the `HasValue` property. This will be `null` until the field is set (or if it was set to `null` explicitly).

Comment: That only works for value types.